# Formulario realiza los procedimientos correctamente al cerrarse y volverse a abrir

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un programa hecho en `C#` y `visual studio 2019` de control de inventario, todo funciona correctamente con los decimales, pero hay veces que cuando el usuario intenta colocar un precio con 4 decimales (ejemplo 0,0007) y al guardar ese numero se transforma en 7, pero cierra y vuelve a abrir el formulario o cierra completamente la aplicación y vuelve a ingresar, y coloca el precio del producto si coje bien la cantidad (ejemplo 0,0007). Esto no ocurre siempre, sucede solo en algunas ocasiones, hay veces que agarra los 4 decimales y hay veces que no. ¿A qué se debe esto?
Hice pruebas y no me muestra ningun error de código.

```
string codProd = txtCodigoProd.Text.Trim();
txtNombreProd.Text = txtNombreProd.Text.ToUpper();
string nombreProd = txtNombreProd.Text.Trim();
string descrip = txtDescripcionProd.Text.Trim();
string stock = txtStockProd.Text.Trim();
string costo = txtCostoProd.Text.Trim();
string precVenta = txtPrecio1PublicoProd.Text.Trim();
string prec2 = txtPrecio2Prod.Text.Trim();
string prec3 = txtPrecio3Prod.Text.Trim();
string medidas = "";
string prov = "";
string tipo = "";
string codigoCuenta = "";
string nombreCuenta = "";

string ConIva = "";

if (costo == "")
{
      var numb = 0;
      costo = Convert.ToString(numb);
}
if (stock == "")
{
      var numb = 0;
      stock = Convert.ToString(numb);
}
if (precVenta == "")
{
      var numb = 0;
      precVenta = Convert.ToString(numb);
}
if (prec2 == "")
{
     var numb = 0;
     prec2 = Convert.ToString(numb);
}
if (prec3 == "")
{
    var numb = 0;
    prec3 = Convert.ToString(numb);
}

mProductos.InsertarProd(nombreProd, codProd, descrip, medidas, stock, costo, ConIva, precVenta, prec2, prec3);
MessageBox.Show("Registro insertado correctamente", "Registro Correcto", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

Comment: En que está hecho (web, winforn, wpf, etc)? Puedes colocar algo de código?

Comment: @Yussef windows-form

Comment: Es probable que sea por la cultura si usas (,) ya que puede estar convirtiendo como si fueran decimales americanos porque (,) se usa para el 1000 (1,000).
Prueba a transformalo añadiendo la cultura: Convert.toDouble(valor,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES").NumberFormat)

Comment: Es imposible contestar esto sin un claro ejemplo... estariamos adivinando...

Comment: @gbianchi a mí me paso en dirección contraria de decimales a string se debe a que coge mal la cultura lo único que encontré funciona si se le especifica.

Comment: @gbianchi, no coloque el codigo porque no lo tenia a la mano en ese momento, pero basicamente este es mi codigo de guardar, funciona bien, lo que comente solo sucede en ocasiones

Comment: @rexxarcat probare eso muchas gracias

Comment: Aparte de lo que te dijeron, notaria y preguntaria, porque estas convirtiendo numeros a cadenas? si son numeros, trabajalos como numeros... no los conviertas a cadena...

Comment: Supongo que `mProductos.InsertarProd` invoca un stored pricedure para realizar el inser en base dr datos; pero ¿Por que le pasa parametros de cadena para valores que se ve por logica que son numericos? Acaso tiene el stored procedure con parametros de cadena? Si es asi: pésima práctica ya que al tener que realizar vonversiomes implovitas de cadena a numerico no puede saber von certeza si es en la aplicación el error de lógica ... o en el stored procedure. Vuelvalo a escribir usando los tipos correctos